# The existing power supply is a large diameter 3 wire line . My new shed has a 10/3 4 wire line coming out of the breaker box. How can i hook it up

Tags: electrical-panel

The existing supply is made up of 3 larger wires a white , black , and a green . The wires coming out of my new breaker box is a new 10/3 4 wire line a black , white , red , and a bare ground wire. On the existing I know the black and white wires both give the same reading on a voltmeter with the green being the ground.

Comment: Is the existing power supply from a power company?

Comment: White is *usually* neutral but for pure 240V circuits that don’t need neutral, it’s the second hot leg. Until very recently it wasn’t even a requirement to re-mark the wire to a hot color when the usage was “obvious”.

Comment: What are you thinking of using power for in shed?  A welder would be okay.  Stuff like lights, small power tools, or a radio will give problems.

Comment: I don't understand which feeder is the 3-wire and which is the 4-wire.

Comment: Where is this existing supply coming from?

Comment: How about giving us a picture of your breaker box, preferebly with the power & the panel cover off. Just [edit] your post, then drag the picture into the text edit box. The site will upload & host the image for you.

Comment: I agree with crip659, we would need to know what you want to connect, and the breaker size that feeds this cable to be able to provide instructions.